# Maven assembly include snapshot depedencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am noticing that maven-assembly-plugin doesnt want to include snapshot dependencies in the assembly jar. Is this by design or am i doing something wrong.

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.zzz</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
```

There are multiple snapshot dependencies like this, so I hate to include them explicitly in the assembly descriptor.

Question 1:
Is there a way to include the snapshot dependencies in the bundle too?

Question 2:
Can you help to figure out how to include all dependencies (compile, test, provided and runtime) in the assembled jar . By default, maven considers only the runtime jars

Following is the maven-assembly section in the pom

```
<plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
```

Here is assembly descriptor file

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>dist</id>
  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  <formats>
  <format>jar</format>
 </formats>
 <dependencySets>
 <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
 </dependencySet>
 </dependencySets>
<fileSets>
<fileSet>
    <includes>
    <include>database/**</include>
    <include>deploy/**</include>
  </includes>
       <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.tmp</exclude
      </excludes>
  <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
 </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Could you please shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

as for question 1, to include snapshot dependencies from the current build, use a moduleSet

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html

that is, if they come from the current reactor. otherwise you will have to build them and depend on a release version.

Answer (score 0):

figured out the answer for 2nd question. Thanks to Bo Ni, who posted this blog: http://bosbluebluesky.blogspot.com/2012/11/maven-package-jar-file-include-all.html

All i had to do was include different scope in multiple dependencyset sections individually

```
 <dependencySets>
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
</dependencySet>
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
</dependencySet>
<dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
 </dependencySet>
  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
    <unpack>false</unpack>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
    <includes></includes>
  </dependencySet>
 </dependencySets>
```